# Does log4net have a message-writing method that accepts a level as a parameter?

Tags: log4net

I am upgrading a C# program that had a simple static FileLogger class that merely writes a line into a text file.  I want to use log4net.  Rather than ripping out the FileLogger class, I figured I could just rewrite that class to use log4net.  The class has a method whose signature is:

```
WriteMessage(string message)
```

I want to replace that with a method that uses this signature:

```
WriteMessage(string message, log4net.core.Level level)
```

But the only way I know to write messages in log4net is to use ILog.Debug(), ILog.Warn(), and so on.  If that's all I have, I'd have to have a truly ugly switch statement in my WriteMessage() method.  Isn't there a better way?

Edit:  I can't even use a switch on a log4net.Core.Level object because Level is a class, not an enumeration.  I should probably just rip out FileLogger entirely and use log4net the way it was meant to be used, but I remain curious.  I'd like to be able to have a message-writing method that uses a level as a parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Log` method on the `ILogger` interface:

```cs
public class TestClass
{
    public TestClass()
    {
        ILog log = LogManager.GetLogger(this.GetType());

        log.Debug("This is debug message");
        log.Logger.Log(this.GetType(), Level.Debug, "Another debug message", null);
    }
}
```